# How to UnitTest System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBoxFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

Edit : I am not trying to UnitTest TextBoxFor, but the code that uses it, However mocking objects and passing it to the code causes null reference exception without any hints on what property did not have a value, som properties like Request can not even be mocked.

How to UnitTest System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBoxFor  ?
From googling around it seems that TextBoxFor is not UnitTestable, one can not mock the required parameters and get a result back, what is a unit testable alternative ?

The overuse static functions in MVC goes everything OO. The base units of in MVC are not even unit testable, or is there a another way to test?

Here is a link to one of the articles I used try to mockup objects so that I can test the custome Html Helper
http://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/unit-testing-html-helpers-for-aspnet-mvc-38638

Comment: Why do you want to test framework code?

Comment: Because a douchbag wrote wrappers around that, and I need to use those wrappers, to make a new helper. I can not UnitTest my code without having a TextBox for sitting right in the middle of the code, I just want to test my code, that is based on somebody elses use of TextboxFor

Comment: @CodeCaster : I just want a rendered output from TextboxFor

Comment: You could of course wrap that wrapper inside a wrapper class with an interface, so you can mock that interface, but that'll quickly become wrapperception...